# Primality Test Comparison

Tags: c, primes, primality-test

I found a new primality test below which determines if 1000000007 is prime.

How does its **speed** compare to other existing primality algorithms?
Does it win the award for most "computationally worthless" primality test?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Was able to improve speed using this method described here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979118/speedup-primality-test

"So it's enough to go from x=n/2 up to n/2+√n/2. With this improvement, your algorithm will still be somewhat slower than your isPrimeNumber routine--just because calculating a gcd is slower than calculating divisibility. This will be feasible for testing numbers with maybe 15-20 digits, but you would need completely different methods to test something much larger, like the 183-digit number you mention."

```
// Primality Test
// Every n is prime if all lattice points on x+y=n are visible from the origin.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>


uint64_t gcd(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return (b != 0) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}


int isPrimeNumber(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 0;

    // Start near line x=y.
    uint64_t x = (n / 2) + 2;
    uint64_t y = n - x;
    uint64_t count = sqrt(n) / 2;

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Check lattice point visibility...
        if (gcd(x, y) != 1) return 0;
        x++; y--;
    }

    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    uint64_t n = 1000000007;

    if (isPrimeNumber(n) == 1)
    {
        printf("%llu prime.", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%llu not prime.", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about computational complexity? Correctness? Anything else?

Comment: For a prime, it has to test approx `n/2` values of `x,y` but for a composite number you might get lucky and find an early result.

Comment: The program reports that `1000000007` is not prime, but it is.

Comment: Check `gcd(x,y)` for `x` only in the range [2, sqrt(n)]. Improvement! `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write any code, you should do basic debugging to verify that your code does what you think it does. Run your code on a few small numbers; print values of `x` and `y` to verify that it does the correct checks.

In addition to this, if you mix integers and floating-point variables, you should be careful: implicit conversions e.g. from `float` to `unsigned` can lead to data loss and completely incorrect calculations. Compilers usually warn about this; you should compile with all warnings enabled `-Wall` and pay attention to what the compiler says.

It looks like you should always have `x + y = n` during your computations - this is your invariant. This can be more easily expressed like this:

```
// initialization
x = n / 2;
y = n - x;
// it should be evident that your invariant holds here

do {
    ...
    x++; y--;
    // your invariant holds here too, by induction
}
```

Comment: After making these mods to the program, it now correctly reports 1000000007 as prime, but it takes **90 seconds** on my machine. Whereas a trial division using divisors to the `sqrt(n)` takes a fraction of a second.